# Toggle text on hover pushes text to the side instead of disappearing

Tags: html, css

I recreated a toggle text on hover using css and html based on this link http://jsfiddle.net/G28qz/

However, I seem to receive a strange error whenever I hover over the link it switches to the second text, but the first text doesnt go away instead it remains in place and pushes the second text to the right.

**So How can I make the second text appear and the first text dissapear when I hover over it?**

This is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nL4guLkL/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="shareactions">

<a href="#" id="mew" class="shareicons">
<span class="nextoicons">Click Me</span>
<span class="hovericons">ScrollMe</span>
</a>

<a href="#" id="mewtwo" class="shareicons">
<span class="nextoicons">Press it</span>
<span class="hovericons">Push it</span>
</a>

<a href="#" id="pika" class="shareicons">
<span class="nextoicons">Hit Me</span>
<span class="hovericons">Punch Me</span>
</a>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.nextoicons { margin-right:10px;}

.shareicons { display:inline-block; width:100%; position:relative; margin-left:5%; white-space:nowrap;}


        /* Hide the second piece of text by default */
    a.shareicons .hovericons {
         display:none; 
    }

    /* Hide the first piece of text on hover */
   a.shareicons:hover .nexttoicons  {
         display:none;
    }

    /* Re-show the second piece of text on hover */

    a.shareicons:hover .hovericons {
        display:inline; 
    }

.shareactions { width:100%; margin-top:-60px; height:40px; background-color:#363; line-height:42px; display:inline-block; float:left;}
```

If anyone can help me figure this out, I would gladly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you spelled the HTML class `nexttoicons` wrong

HTML

```
nextoicons
```

CSS

```
nexttoicons
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nL4guLkL/2/)

Comment: Lol, you're right. I don't know how I missed that. Thanks mate!

Comment: @user3771570 no problem, we've all been there. Can you check this off as resolved when you get a chance?